# module call error. cant loop input function

Tags: python, loops, input, module

I want to call module function and loop. But when i loop, input window just open once and show none.

```
#This is my module function. file name is calc.py

def gain1():
    a = int(input("Type first number : "))
    b = int(input("Type Second number : "))  


    if a % 2 == 0 : 
        a = a + 1

    elif a % 2 == 1 :
        a = a - 1

    if b % 2 == 0 :
        b = b + 1

    elif b % 2 == 1 :
        b = b - 1

    print(a+b)


sum1 = gain1()
```

And this is my Main file

```
import calc #import gain1 function
d = 1

while d < 10:
    print(calc.sum1)
    d = d + 1
```

And this is result

```
Type first number : 3

Type Second number : 4

7
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

I want to repeat type things, but it only repeat once, and 9 times repeat show None. 
I just want to know why. Can you tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I dont suggest to get input from another file, instead you can use variables in function. You can use something like this:

```py
def gain1(a,b):
...
```

you're still getting input, but in better way. Your code can look like this:


calc.py should look like:

```py
#This is my module function. file name is calc.py

def gain1(a,b):
    # asigning variables from above
    if a%2 == 0 : 
        a = a + 1

    elif a%2 == 1 :
        a = a - 1

    elif b%2 == 0 :
        b = b + 1

    elif b%2 == 1 :
        b = b - 1
    #you need to return it to not display None
    return a+b
```

To get rid of the None you need to do `return a+b`. by making `def gain(a,b)` you're getting input from calling the function.


main.py should look like:

```py
import calc #import gain1 function
d = 1
#getting variables
input1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
input2 = int(input("enter second number: "))

while d < 10:
    # adding numbers into the function in calc.py
    print(calc.gain1(input1,input2))
    d = d + 1
```

Here you get input of numbers and them assigning them onto a `calc.gain(input1,input2)`. this is all the code you need to fix your problem. I hope it helps!


if you want to loop the input simply put it in the loop, or you can loop in the function `gain1` in `calc.py`.